# Django JSON list of classes containing list of classes - correct de-serialization and representation in JSON to Model?

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, deserialization

In Django 1.6 I am using `serializers.deserialize` to try and deserialize the following JSON (which I serialized manually on the client side) into the following models..

** The JSON is supposed to represent a list of objects, and each object contains a list of objects again. So a list of "test" and each test contains a list of "subtest" - like the following:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1, 
        "model": "polls.test", 
        "fields": {
            "category": "CategoryThing", 
            "parent_name": "parent_test_name_1",
            'subtest': [
                       {'pk': 2,
                        'model': 'polls.subtest',
                        'fields': {'status': 'passed',
                                   'regression_status': 'disabled',
                                   'name': 'sub_test_name_1'
                                   }
                       }, 
                       {'pk': 2, // corrct pk ?
                        'model': 'polls.subtest',
                        'fields': {'status': 'passed',
                                   'regression_status': 'enabled',
                                   'name': 'sub_test_name_2'
                                   }
                       }

    }, 
    // more parent test objects containing multiple subtest objects like above..
]
```

**My problem came along when trying to represent the list inside JSON as Django models - so when deserializing the subtest**, and when removing the embedded array/list from my JSON.
I *thought* that the best way to represent that in a Django model was to have **two model classes**, one for the parent test (**Test**) and one for the sub-test (**SubTest**) like so:

```
class Test(models.Model):
  parent_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  category = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class SubTest(models.Model):
  test = models.ForeignKey('Test', related_name='subtest')
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  regression_status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

### My Question(s)

- **How best to represent the class containing a list of classes in Django models?** I thought in order to represent that association, a `ForeignKey` was needed in the SubTest class "pointing" to an entry in Test.
- As I am encoding the JSON manually with `JSONEncoder`. Therefore I am constructing the pk, model and fields and everything you see in the JSON above, myself. **Does it look correct for a list containing python objects of classes which contain lists of objects again?** The (very rough) UML for what I am trying to achieve is very streightforward and is a 1 to many relationship between Test and SubTest. So Test has many SubTests. And Tests are all in a list.

---

```
+------------+ 1    *..1 +------------+   1     1..*  +----------+  
|    list    |---------->|    Test    |<>-------------| SubTest  |  
|     of     |           |            |               |          |  
|    Tests   |           |            |               |          |  
+------------+           +------------+               +----------+
```

I appreciate any help or input.

---

Edits: Changed name, added more detail to problem.

Comment: Regarding your first question my advice is to use `related_name`, for example: `test = models.ForeignKey('Test', related_name='subtest')`. This adds implicitly a field `subtest` to the class Test.

Comment: @cezar I see, thanks for the response.. Does that mean I still need to insert some sort of empty entry in Test?  The SQL output after doing a sync doesn't show the result of doing `related_name='subtest'.

Comment: No, you don't have to add anything to Test. Defining a `related_name='subtest'` in the class `SubTest` in the field `test` will enable backward relation. Let's say: `test = Test.objects.get(pk=1)`, `test.subtest.all()` will then return all subtests assigned to the test with primary key 1.

Comment: The SQL output won't show you anything for the class Test. The related names are only Django related. They are not mapped in the SQL.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I still get `Test has no field named u'subtest'.`  I will keep digging for something stupid I may have done wrong..

Comment: I tried swapping around the cardinality and making the subtest element a foreign key in the Test model with related_name=test, but this leads to more problems and now the embedded JSON array cannot be deserialized.